# Bash Script compare strings and variable in an if statement

Tags: string, bash, variables, comparison

I am trying to get a variable to compare to a string, and then do something if it does and go on to the next, but when i look at it in debug mode, the variable just shows up as `''` with nothing in it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Enter the name of the document you wish to edit:\c"
read dname
CTYPE= file "$dname" | cut -d\  -f2
echo $CTYPE
VAR="ASCII"
VAR2="cannot"
if [ "$CTYPE" == "$VAR" ]
then
    vi $dname                       
fi
```

I get this result:

```
+ VAR=ASCII
+ VAR2=cannot
+ '[' '' == ASCII ']'
```

Where the `''` is empty even though I `echo`d it and see that it is not empty.

I have tried it like these other ways as well, and get the same or similar non working result:

```
CTYPE= file "$dname" | cut -d\  -f2
if [ "$CTYPE" == "$VAR" ]

ctype= file "$dname" | cut -d\  -f2
if [ $ctype = "ASCII" ]

ctype= file "$dname" | cut -d\  -f2
if [ "$ctype" = "ASCII" ]   

ctype= file "$dname" | cut -d\  -f2
if [ "$ctype" == "ASCII" ]
```

Not sure what I am missing, I've read so many posts I don't know where to go from here. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have an error with CTYPE:

```
CTYPE=$(file "$dname" | cut -d\  -f2)
```

You cannot have **any** spaces between the `=` and the assignment. Further, you want the return from `file "$dname" | cut -d\  -f2` so you will have to enclose it in `$()` or with backticks.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this command:

```
d= date
```

bash does this: set an environment variable `d` (with the value the empty string) **only** for the duration of the `date` command. This is densely documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion).

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25337913/7552) tells you, to capture the outut of a command, you need

```
d=$(date)
```